# Not able to perform click event on dynamically created html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jquery and creating some `ul`, `li` and `a` dynamically on `$('document').ready()`. After this the `ul`-`li` renders in browser is looks like bellow in html representation

```
                    <ul class="ul">
                        <li class="li">
                            <a>Some buddy</a>
                            <ul class="ul">
                                <li class="li" id="testLi">
                                    <a id="testView">test buddy</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Please ignore class names. I have assigned ids to `<li> and child`` tags. and I also have a function written as bellow:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#testView').click(function () {
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.className = 'ul';

         var li = document.createElement('li');
         li.className = 'li';
         var a = document.createElement('a');
         a.innerHTML = 'test buddy';
         $(li).append(a);
         $(ul).append(li);

        $('#testLi').append(ul);
    });
});
```

Now if I click on `<a id="testView">test buddy</a>` my function does not get called. I think this because DOM is loaded and my new elements are get created in `ready()`. Please provide a solution.

Comment: Do you want this script when the page is loaded or when the user clicks on the <a id="testView">test buddy</a>

Comment: I copy pasted your code and it's working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/agL6y7kv/)

Comment: @WisdmLabs that's because HTML in your fiddle is static, while in question it is somehow generated later in code.

Comment: @Regent check now, I am adding HTML dynamically by js and it's also working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/agL6y7kv/1/)

Comment: @WisdmLabs you should add elements after event handler to reproduce the problem: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agL6y7kv/2/)

Comment: @Regent you are right. haxtbh answer is useful. I Corrected [here](http://jsfiddle.net/agL6y7kv/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to attach the event handler to the document and delegate the event to the element.

You can do something like this:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#testView', function () {
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.className = 'ul';

         var li = document.createElement('li');
         li.className = 'li';
         var a = document.createElement('a');
         a.innerHTML = 'test buddy';
         $(li).append(a);
         $(ul).append(li);

        $('#testLi').append(ul);
    });
```

This will apply to all the elements with this id regardless of whether they are created before document.ready() or not.

Comment: This is not necessary if the event listener get's added after the dom object got created

Comment: Its not, but he is adding them dynamically after the document is loaded.

Comment: @Markai for all that I understand from question, these DOM elements are created after event handler binding.

Comment: Of course, if they are created afterwards, event delegation is needed, just said, that if that isn't the case, it's not necessary

Answer (score -1):

Your code is working fine. I have added it to the snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#testView').click(function() {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    ul.className = 'ul';

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = 'li';
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.innerHTML = 'test buddy';
    $(li).append(a);
    $(ul).append(li);

    $('#testLi').append(ul);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul">
  <li class="li">
    <a>Some buddy</a>
    <ul class="ul">
      <li class="li" id="testLi">
        <a id="testView">test buddy</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```